# How can I extract 2-depth json data from my server in ruby?

Tags: ruby, xml, json

This is my json data from our server.

```
{"id":3,"status":"Fix","severity":"Error","severityCode":2,"state":"Existing","c
ode":"MLK.MUST","message":"Memory leak. Dynamic memory stored in \u0027new_cat\u
0027 allocated through function \u0027malloc\u0027 at line 11 is lost at line 31
","file":"/data001/tools/test/test.c","method":"main","owner":"unowned","taxonom
yName":"C and C++","url":"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/insight-review.html
#goto:project\u003dTest,pid\u003d3"}
```

If I convert this to xml, I can find the data below from the xml file.

```
<taxonomyName>C and C++</taxonomyName>
```

However, If I export xml from my web server menu directly, the file includes data such like

```
<taxonomies>
 <taxonomy name="C and C++" metaInf=""/>
</taxonomies>
```

I think that this different result comes out because I generated wrong json data.
I used the following code to get json data from my server.

```
url_string = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8088/review/api?action=search&user=wbt&project=Test&ltoken='
uri = URI(url_string)
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'q' => 'ruby')
```

Could you let me know which of my codes cause this problem?

Thanks alot.

**UPDATE**
I modified my script below. And I can get the result as I expect

```
  my_xml.each_line do |line|
   next if line.start_with?("<?xml") or line.eql?("<hash>") or line.eql?("</hash>")   
   if line.include?("<taxonomyName>")     
     issues.puts "  <taxonomies>"
     issues.puts "    <taxonomy name=\"#{results["taxonomyName"]}\"/>"
     issues.puts "  </taxonomies>"
   else
     issues.puts line
   end
  end
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. The title makes it sound like you need help getting "C and C++" out of your JSON using Ruby... is that still the goal?

Comment: *I used the following code to get json data from my server.* That is generic code that mimics submitting a form on a web page.  The server could send any type of response after receiving that request. Re-program your server to send you xml if that is what you want.

Comment: Our server removed the function which sending xml. So I got json data by using web api and then I am trying to convert the json format data to xml. @7stud

Comment: For what purpose? Why not just retrieve your data from the json?

Comment: My purpose is to generate a xml file from json data. However, my converted xml is different from the one which I export from web browser. So I wonder how I can get the same result. @7stud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'json'

json_hash = JSON.parse(<<'END_OF_JSON')
{
  "owner":"unowned",
  "taxonomyName":"C and C++",
  "taxonomyColor":"red",
  "url":"hello.com",
  "ownerAge":"20"
}
END_OF_JSON

tag_attrs = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "" }

json_hash.keys.each do |key|
  capital_index = key.index(/[A-Z]/)

  if capital_index
    tag_name = key[0...capital_index]
    attr_name = key[capital_index..-1].downcase
    tag_attrs[tag_name] << %Q{ #{attr_name}="#{json_hash[key]}"}
  else
    tag_attrs[key] #Because of the way the tag_attrs Hash was created, this creates an entry in the tag_attrs Hash.
  end
end

tag_attrs.each do |tag_name, all_attrs|
  puts "<#{tag_name}#{all_attrs}>#{json_hash[tag_name]}</#{tag_name}>"
end

--output:--
<owner age="20">unowned</owner>
<taxonomy name="C and C++" color="red"></taxonomy>
<url>hello.com</url>
```

Comment: Thanks @7stud And I also modified my script using other approach.